# PHP Regex to find pattern and wrap in anchor tags

Tags: php, regex, pattern-matching, preg-replace, preg-match

I have a string with movie titles and release year. I want to be able to detect the Title (Year) pattern and if matched wrap it in anchor tags.

Wrapping it is easy. But is it possilbe to write a regex to match this pattern if I don't know what the name of the movie would be?

Example:

```
$str = 'A random string with movie titles in it. 
Movies like The Thing (1984) and other titles like Captain America Civil War (2016). 
The movies could be anywhere in this string. 
And some movies like 28 Days Later (2002) could start with a number.';
```

So the pattern will always be `Title` (starting with uppercase letter) and will end with `(Year)`.

This is what I have got so far:

```
if(preg_match('/^\p{Lu}[\w%+\/-]+\([0-9]+\)/', $str)){
    error_log('MATCH');
}
else{
    error_log('NO MATCH');
}
```

This currently does not work. From what I understand this is what it should do:

`^\p{Lu} //match a word beginning with an uppercase letter`

`[\w%+\/-] //with any number of characters following it`

`+\([0-9]+\) //ending with an integer`

Where am I going wrong with this?

Comment: `([A-Z]{1}[a-z]+\s?)+\(\d+\)` This is what you're looking for. For easy testing of regex patterns i use RegExr (http://regexr.com/)

Comment: Might a line start right away with a movie title?  What if a movie is fully numeric like `1984 (1984)`?  Is this something that needs to be catered for?  siam's solution, while very smart, doesn't match `1984 (1984) is a movie over 30 years old.`  I merely want to make sure your provided samples cover all possible occurrences.

Comment: On the other hand, toto's regex captures `1984 (1984) is a movie over 30 years old.` and with a saving of 164 steps.  It seems superior against my expanded sample.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following *regex* should do it :

```
(?-i)(?<=[a-z]\s)[A-Z\d].*?\(\d+\)
```

**Explanation**

- `(?-i)` case-sensitive
- `(?<=[a-z]\s)` look-behind for any lower-case letter and space
- `[A-Z\d]` match an upper-case letter or digit
- `.*?` match any character
- `\(\d+\)` match any digits including parenthesis

**[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/0Xvuuz/1)**

**PHP**

```
<?php
$regex = '/(?-i)(?<=[a-z]\s)[A-Z\d].*?\(\d+\)/';
$str = 'A random string with movie titles in it.
       Movies like The Thing (1984) and other titles like Captain America Civil War (2016).
       The movies could be anywhere in this string.
       And some movies like 28 Days Later (2002) could start with a number.';
preg_match_all($regex, $str, $matches);
print_r($matches);
?>
```

Comment: Great answer and thanks for the explanation. I was a long way off!

Answer (score 0):

This regex does the job:

```
~(?:[A-Z][a-zA-Z]+\s+|\d+\s+)+\(\d+\)~
```

**Explanation:**

```
~               : regex delimiter
  (?:           : start non capture group
    [A-Z]       : 1 capital letter, (use \p{Lu} if you want to match title in any language)
    [a-zA-Z]+   : 1 or more letter,  if you want to match title in any language(use \p{L})
    \s+         : 1 or more spaces
   |            : OR
    \d+         : 1 or more digits
    \s+         : 1 or more spaces
  )+            : end group, repeated 1 or more times
  \(\d+\)       : 1 or more digits surrounded by parenthesis, (use \d{4} if the year is always 4 digits)
~               : regex delimiter
```

**Implementation:**

```
$str = 'A random string with movie titles in it. 
Movies like The Thing (1984) and other titles like Captain America Civil War (2016). 
The movies could be anywhere in this string. 
And some movies like 28 Days Later (2002) could start with a number.';

if (preg_match_all('~(?:[A-Z][a-zA-Z]+\s+|\d+\s+)+\(\d+\)~', $str, $match)) {
    print_r($match);
    error_log('MATCH');
}
else{
    error_log('NO MATCH');
}
```

**Result:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => The Thing (1984)
            [1] => Captain America Civil War (2016)
            [2] => 28 Days Later (2002)
        )

)
MATCH
```